# How can I download all my files and folders in one go when using the Ubuntu One Files app for Android?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, android

I just installed Ubuntu One on my Android phone. I want to download all the content of my Ubuntu One folder in one go. Looks to me like the only way it is to go one by one file and folder clicking to download. I understand this is to help users with small storage space and/or 3G connections. But I am connecting via wifi and I have a 16G card so this is not an issue for me.

Is there a way to force to download all in one go?

Answer (score 5):

You can download all your Ubuntu One content in one go using the Android app but you'll have to do a little rearranging because you can't download the default "Ubuntu One" folder all in one go.

To achieve this, on your computer create a new folder within the default Ubuntu One folder, then cut and paste everything you wish to upload into the new folder.

Now when you launch the Android app select your Ubuntu One folder and you should see the new folder within, **press and hold** on this and a menu will pop-up, select **Download** from this menu and all of the contents of the folder will be downloaded

Note from developer: Please note that this is currently a flat, non recursive download, so it will download only files within that directory (but not child directories).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Has far as I know, there's no "file syncing" process with Ubuntu-One for Android. I checked on all settings and even tried with the web-client but there's no option to retrieve a full folder in one row!

Comment: I actually copied the whole folder manually from my desktop into the phone's sdcrad u1/Ubuntu One folder but ubuntuone does not see that the files are already there